# wordpress importer 0.6.1 not installed properly with WP 3.8.1

Tags: wordpress

it gives error:

```
 Strict standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class WXR_Parser_Regex in
    C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-importer\parsers.php on line 408
```

but also displays that it installed succesfully... so is there something to worry about? i tried to import and it did fine...